# Seat mounting rails bent out of shape

Tags: parts, saddle, terminology

Recently I crashed my bike, and since then, the seat has been tilted towards the left side.

I know very little about bikes and the associated terminology, but I think what happened is that the rails that are used to mount the seat have been bent out of shape in the accident; see the images attached below.

What I'd like to know is:

1. What's the proper terminology here (e.g. regarding the "rails")?
2. Can I, or a repair shop, bend the rails back into shape without seriously compromising safety?
3. It looks to me like the seat itself is secured to a mounting plate (which is connected to the rails) with something akin to Allen screws. Are these mounting plates standard parts that I can replace, to salvage the seat? If so, what are they called?

Thanks!

[image: Seat picture 1]
[image: Seat picture 2]
[image: Seat picture 3]

Comment: There may be more than just bent saddle rails. The clamp (that part with the Allen bolts), the seat post head or the post it-self may have been affected. Could you post a sideways picture of the frame to the top of the saddle?

Comment: @Carel: Thanks for the additional hints! I don't have the parts with me right now, but I removed the damaged saddle and replaced it with a spare one I had, and now everything looks OK to the untrained eye. So I guess the clamp and post are fine.

Comment: Generally speaking, rails cannot be swapped unless its a high-end saddle (ie expensive).  That small plastic plate under the nose will come off, but the rails will be epoxied to the rest of it.  You might try to use a crowbar or a big screwdriver for leverage, but things will be weakened.  Just remember to look closely with your monthly safety check and keep an eye on it.

Comment: Don’t just look if anything is bend, also look if there are cracks anywhere. Especially around the top of the seat tube (+seatpost clamp), seat stays etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Saddle) rails is the correct term. They are part of the saddle/seat. I’m not aware of any saddle where they are replaceable.

You might be able to bend the rails back but it could compromise stability. Considering a new saddle only costs a couple of euros I’d just replace it.

For a crash to bend the rails like that it takes quite some force. I recommend a very careful inspection of the frame, seat post and all other parts of the bicycle.

Comment: Agreed - a good inspection would be smart.  OP might want to get a bike shop or someone else to look with a fresh eye.